# get a DOM element with class="B" inside of an element with class="A"

Tags: javascript, html

Having this HTML structure:

```html
<div class="fruit">
  <div class="tomato">get this one</div>
</div>
<div class="vegetable">
  <div class="tomato">not this one</div>
</div>
```

How would one get the `.tomato` element that is inside the `.fruit` element, and not the one inside `.vegetable` using Javascript?

Example:

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("fruit");
b = a.FunctionThatGetsTheClass("tomato");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative is using selector along with the function [`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> The [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

```
let tomatos = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit .tomato');
```

```js
let tomatos = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit .tomato');
// The function map is only to demonstrate the selected elements.
console.log(Array.from(tomatos).map(d => d.textContent));
```

```html
<div class="fruit">
  <div class='tomato'>tomatos#1</div>
  <div class='tomato'>tomatos#2</div>
</div>
<div class="vegetable">
  <div class='tomato'>tomatos#3</div>
  <div class='tomato'>tomatos#4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use such things as .innerHTML with this method?

Comment: @Damn Hello, what you mean? use innerHTML within the selector?

Comment: Yes, to get the inner html of the class that we're selecting.

Comment: @Damn can you elaborate your doubt inside of the question's body?

Answer (score 3):

Use `querySelector` (or `querySelectorAll`) instead, to which you can pass a query string which allows for this sort of DOM traversal very succinctly:

```
const tomato = document.querySelector('.fruit .tomato');
```

will select the first `.tomato` element which is an eventual descendants of a `.fruit` element.

If you want to select *all* elements which fulfill those conditions, use `querySelectorAll` instead:

```
const tomatoes = document.querySelectorAll('.fruit .tomato');
```

Note that `getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* `HTMLCollection`, while `querySelectorAll` returns a (static) `NodeList`, which are slightly different. (in addition to the live vs static difference, I think the biggest difference to keep in mind is that `NodeList`s have a `forEach` method in modern browsers - which is convenient - but `HTMLCollection`s don't)